# Баг с бейджами и уведомлениями

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, знаки

Пришло уведомление о восьми бронзовых бейджах:

- 3 "Сторонник"
- 4 "Учитель"
- 1 "Младший редактор"

Однако же в профиле отображается только "Автобиограф".

Comment: Все ли работает сейчас? Возможно это был кэш?

Comment: Отсутствие знаков скорее всего кэш, о чём я писал в комментарии к ответу ниже... Меня больше смущают мультиуведомления.

Answer (score 3):

У вас несколько профилей в [Сети](http://stackexchange.com/users/2416609/vp-arth?tab=accounts), соответственно знаки были добавлены для соответствующих профилей и отображаются они в профиле для каждого из сообществ отдельно. На [«Stackoverflow на русском»](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) у вас 4 знака. Имхо, все верно. По крайней мере у других участников (насколько я успел заметить) со знаками все в порядке.

Comment: Уведомления пришли по конкретному ресурсу и на русском языке. Во-первых, уведомления пришли по нескольку раз(баг). Во-вторых, после уведомлений в профиле на этом ресурсе был один бейдж(+1 баг), уведомление о котором не приходило(+1 баг). На данный момент в профиле 6 "знаков", среди которых есть все "знаки" из уведомлений, из чего я делаю вывод, что виной тому, некий кеш.